# copy/transfer eclipse from one ubuntu(linux) machine to other

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I have eclipse downloaded on one of my ubuntu machines. and now I want eclipse on my other ubuntu machine.
how can I do this?

Comment: I wonder why your question has neither been commented yet nor answered. I have same question.

Answer (score 0):

In the computer you have eclipse installed:

Backup the folder containing eclipse (usually it's in the /opt folder)

> sudo cp -r /opt/eclipse /folder/to/backup/eclipse

In the one you want eclipse to be installed:

1. Copy eclipse to the opt folder

> sudo cp -r /backup/eclipse /opt/eclipse

1. Add read permission to all files

> chmod -R +r /opt/eclipse

1. Add the executable bit to the eclipse binary

> chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse

1. Add an executalbe entry to /usr/bin

> sudo touch /usr/bin/eclipse
>
> sudo chmod +x /usr/bin eclipse

1. Edit the created file with your favourite editor.

> sudo gedit -w /usr/bin/eclipse

and paste the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse" 
$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

At this point you should be able to run `eclipse` from command line, If you want to add a desktop entry, investigate how to do this in your desktop environment.

Comment: Why not just preserve the original permissions/ownership etc. with `cp -a /opt/eclipse /folder/to/backup/eclipse`