# Moving Eclipse from Debian To Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, debian

I want to move my eclipse folder from a Debian VM to a Ubuntu VM.

Can I just copy over the whole directory, or perhaps just copy over the plugins directory as obviously the project file will work. (the 2 important parts I would prefer not to recreate).

Is there any more hints you could give me on this -- other directories to move, or gotchas I might run into?

Moving it from development VM to another will save me a lot of time.

Thanks very much.

Will Ferrer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the entire eclipse folder and everything should be fine, beware of path you might have edit or add in `ini` files, that's all.

Additionnal and detailled steps are described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461716/copy-transfer-eclipse-from-one-ubuntulinux-machine-to-other) if you're not at ease with linux

Comment: Hi Flafoux. Thanks so much. I will try that. All the best. Will Ferrer